# std::vector inaccessibility with const onject

Tags: c++, vector, constants, operator-keyword, ostream

I was trying to overload the << operator for the Histogram class, whose header file is:

```
#ifndef HISTOGRAM_H
#define HISTOGRAM_H
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

class Histogram{
    private:
        std::vector<float>   listOfElements;
        std::vector<float>  sortedListOfElements;
        std::vector<float>  bucketValues;
        std::vector<float>  bucketFrequencies;
        int numberOfBuckets;
        void setSortedListOfElements();
        void setBucketValues();
        void setBucketFrequencies();
        

    public:
        Histogram(std::vector<float>, int = 10);
        Histogram(const Histogram &obj);
        ~Histogram();

        

        std::vector<float> getListOfElements();
        std::vector<float> getSortedListOfElements();
        std::vector<float> getBucketValues();
        std::vector<float> getBucketFrequencies();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Histogram &hs);

        static float truncfn(float x);

};
```

This is what I tried, in `Histogram.cpp`

```
ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const Histogram &hs){
        out.precision(4);
        out<<fixed;
        int k;
        vector<float>vals = hs.bucketValues;
        vector<float>freq = hs.bucketFrequencies;
        for(k = 0; k<10; k++){
            out<<showpoint<<hs.truncfn(vals[k])<<",";
        }
        out<<showpoint<<hs.truncfn(vals[k])<<" ";
        int j;
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            out<<showpoint<<hs.truncfn(freq[j])<<",";
        }
        out<<showpoint<<hs.truncfn(freq[j]);
        return out;
}
```

However, `bucketValues` and `bucketFrequencies` are inaccessible from this const object, hs. How do I get around this?
I need the function parameter to have a const, as this << operator is being used in another class with `Histogram` composed in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Mark your getter methods `const` then use those?

Comment: Can you post the exact verbatim error message please? Wha are you callin `truncFn()` in your output operator? This seems wrong there (whatever this function is supposed to do), and it's the only part the compiler complains about.

Comment: `hs.truncfn` —> `Histogram::truncfn`.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this, I've tested your code, it compiles fine using C++11

Comment: @TigerYu Strange! It said unreachable for me then

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The reason I was calling truncfn() was to format the output correctly; which was the role of that function. It gives the correct precision of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code you are not using "`using namespace std`" in the header, which is correct, so `ostream` is not defined (unless it is made a member of the global namespace in bits, which would be bad) and the compiler may treat the two occurrences of `ostream` as different types so the `friend operator<<` declared in Histogram class has a different type than the function `operator<<` in your cpp file. Try using `std::ostream`, instead.

You can also improve the code by not copying the vectors in `operator<<` - use references, or better, const references:

```
const vector<float>& vals = hs.bucketValues;
const vector<float>& freq = hs.bucketFrequencies;
```

Comment: You're right! I forgot the using namespace std :) 
The const references is a great idea, thanks a lot :)